# How can I setState in a another components useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

A quick view of what I'm trying to do:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MainComponent = () => {
  const [element, setElement] = useState([]);
  const [setThings] = useSomething();
  useEffect(() => {
    setThings(element);
  }, [element]);
};

const useSomething = () => {
  const [things, setThings] = useState([]);
  // do stuff now that you've received things
  return [setThings];
};
```

and another hook in another file. This works perfectly fine, and is an excellent solution for working with a canvas in reactjs. I have a warning that is throw and I can't seem to sort it out with my research:

```
  Line 150:7:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setThings'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

In the react docs it says this causes issues because the it is calling something that has depencancy's but I'm unse where they are?

Comment: Error message is pretty clear and even tells you what to do. `setThings` is missing from the dependency array, either add it [`setThings`] to the dependency array or remove the dependency array entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `setThings` to dependencies array in `useEffect`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setThings(element);
}, [element, setThings]);
```